# Create attractive section

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, section-titles

[image]

I want to create the section style according to the image could you please guide me how I can create?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scimisc-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}




\begin{document}

% \maketitle %% This is LaTeX's default title constructed from \title,\author,\date

\makecvtitle %% This is a custom command constructing the CV title from \cvname, \cvpersonalinfo

\section{Summary}

\end{document}
```

The scimic package can be found here on overleaf:
[Scismic's Recommended CV Template for Biotech and Pharma Jobs](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/scismics-recommended-cv-template-for-biotech-and-pharma-jobs/hbnkjrjnnpjz)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111463/discussion-between-sagarkumar-zalavadiya-and-andrec).

Comment: Comments have been moved to the chat, so I cleaned up here, thanks for moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom macro to format section heading using the `sectsty` package.  If you need more flexibility, consider using the `titlesec` package, or switch to a more versatile document class like one of the KOMA classes or `memoir`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\boxedsection[1]{%
    \noindent
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1.4em}\rule[-3ex]{1pt}{2ex}}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-2ex]{\dimexpr\textwidth-5pt\relax}{1pt}}%
    \colorbox{brown}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1}}%
}
\allsectionsfont{\boxedsection}
\begin{document}

\section*{CAREER PROFILE}

\end{document}
```

[image]